# Application ID in gcm android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working with GCM, and I am confused about where my application ID is within the GCM settings - is it project ID? Also where do I specify it?

Comment: Where are you trying to use this "application ID"?

Comment: when I send push notification I need to give the "registeration id

Comment: This was a valid question. Where can I find the App ID?

Answer (score 4):

Sender ID - The Sender Id is the id form the browser URL when you sign in to Google APIs Console Page to create project. A project ID you acquire from the API console, as described in Getting Started. The sender ID is used in the registration process to identify an Android application that is permitted to send messages to the device.

Application ID - The Android application that is registering to receive messages. The Android application is identified by the package name from the manifest. This ensures that the messages are targeted to the correct Android application.

check this link for more -

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your project at https://code.google.com/apis/console Google APIs Console page, your browser URL will change to something like:

```
     https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:4815162342
```

Take note of the value after #project: (**4815162342** in this example). This is your project ID, and is used as the GCM sender ID.

Source:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: Should we encrypt the sender id?